# How to run query contains sql variable by pdo

Tags: mysql, pdo

I want to run a query that contains a sql variable by pdo

```
$q = "SET @mydate = '2015/11/07';
SELECT * FROM `t_news` WHERE `date`> @mydate
";
```

phpmyadmin run this query successfully
but mysql_query() OR pdo->execute() return fail

Comment: Please show a bit more of your code where you call the query and reference `$q`.

Comment: Also, don't forget to include your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your connection is open, you can use a variable you've created.

So just set your variable first :

```
$mysqli->query("SET @mydate = '2015/11/07'");
```

or

```
$query = $db->prepare("SET @mydate = '2015/11/07'");
$query->execute();
```

And then use it

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `t_news` WHERE `date`> @mydate";  
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

or

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `t_news` WHERE `date`> @mydate");
$query->execute();
// and then
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```